# Can't use StreamWriter and '\' char at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, character, streamwriter

```
void addFile(string aFile)
{

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\"+ aFile))
         sw.WriteLine("Some Text");
}
```

If the text contains `/` character I get the error that can't find such directory.

Example: `aFile="1/2 Half.c"` => `C:/1/2 Half.c` => Directory 1 doesn't exist.

How can I put the string `"1/2 Half.txt"` in C:\ or any file that contains `/` or maybe `\`?

Comment: try googling path.combine and use that instead of simple string concatenation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Comment: "1/2 Half.txt" is not valid filename.

Answer (score 6):

There are several reserved characters that are illegal in file names. '/' and '\' are two of them.

Here are the guidelines for file naming from the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions

Answer (score 3):

The slash you are using is an invalid character for a filename.

Answer (score 2):

Replace invalid chars with a valid one. You can use [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) for this.

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
var newFileName = new string(
                        fname.Select(c=>invalidChars.Contains(c)?'_':c).ToArray());
```